# What are the undocumented values for referencing_class in sys.sql_expression_dependencies?

Tags: sql-server, metadata, system-tables

In SQL Server, the [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies` system catalog view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql) "Contains one row for each by-name dependency on a user-defined entity in the current database", to quote the docs. One of the returned columns is `referencing_class`, of which the docs say this:

> `referencing_class`   **tinyint**     Class of the referencing entity.
>
> - 1 = Object or column
> - 12 = Database DDL trigger
> - 13 = Server DDL trigger
>
> Is not nullable.

However, I'm looking at a database right now in which there is a row with `referencing_class` equal to 7. What does 7 mean, and what is the correct list of possible values here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This deficiency in the docs [was raised as an issue in August 2019](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2745), with MS comment being

> We've created an internal work item (1595947) to investigate and
> potentially update the article.
>
> We're going to close to this item and track with our internal work
> item

Until such time as MS update the article (or accept a PR against the docs), here is a probably-partial list of the other possible values:

---

```
referencing_class referencing_class_desc
----------------- ----------------------
7                 INDEX
9                 STATISTICS
```

- 7 = *Filtered index* (note that regular unfiltered indexes do not feature in this system view at all)
- 9 = *Filtered* statistics

[This Microsoft Support Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-data-types) shows `referencing_class = 7` in relation to filtered indexes.

Based on the Remarks [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) there are no others probably.